# Bootcamped Mac - When booting no option to select mac

Tags: bootcamp, windows, startup

So I installed windows 10 bootcamp on my new Macbook Pro 13" and was working fine. I could boot in to either windows or mac

I've just restarted this morning and when I hold the alt key down I only have the windows drive as an option to boot into.

In Windows using the boot camp options I can re-boot in mac os and it shows me the apple icon and then boots windows and I can also see the mac drive here.

Any ideas?

Comment: 1 Hardrive with macOS & windows just isn't something god intended to be. There are a thousand possible reasons. Did you update macos? We just ahd an update. Did you use a disk utility (ANY File System altering App, or windows program!) ? Did you install all the drivers after a successful boot into windows? .. You need to give some info.

Comment: Start here: Go into recovery if you want your macOS. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314 from here, I have no doubt it'll be a Hard Drive format issue, resulting in macOS unable to boot.

Comment: Used built in bootcamp assistant to create the partition, haven't done anything manual.

Installed all the windows updates and like I said both were working fine and now suddenly boot drive for mac is gone.

Have started in recovery mode but its doing it over the internet

Comment: Everyone does it through bootcamp, the reason you have to use bootcamp is because Windows and macOS require 2 different *file systems* on a single disk that shouldn't be. If ANY partition gets corrupted, altered, or even updated wrong will result in your dual-boot not working. Simply put: mac can't read windows file system, windows cant read mac's. So if you're on windows and it changes a macOS partition, it'll result in macOS being unreadable by the firmware. EI. No macOS boot option.

Comment: This is a constantly repeated event for everyone that dual-boots. A Linux-macOS dual-boots is the same unstable position since linux's bootable filesystem is the same as windows. Operating Systems love mounting a filesystem partition and poking files on their own since they don't know a thing about the other OS on the disk. macOS does this with Spotlight whenever you insert any USB, hardrive, etc, the moment it mounts.

Comment: In the end, save yourself the trouble and Bootcamp onto an external harddrive that is not touching your internal SSD/HD. It'll save you a possible data loss in the future. SOURCES: I world-first dual-booted the first Macbook Pro Retina (10,1) hours after release in 2012. :)